# HIT templates of Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: mechanicalturk

I think there are default templates for HITs in Mturk, but I can't check them by myself because I can't log in to my account now for some reasons.

Could anyone tell me the names of the templates and what kind of HIT they are?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mechanical Turk Requester Website (http://requester.mturk.com/) there are templates for the following types of HITs:

- Survey Link
- Survey
- Tagging of an Image
- Moderation of an Image
- Writing
- Data Collection
- Transcription from A/V
- Transcription from an Image

There are also two "applications" that are designed to be more full-featured and go beyond templates (they also have some limitations that templates don't have, including that you can't change the HTML and you can't unselect Masters Workers). These are:

- Sentiment
- Categorization

You can also use the "Other" template to create your own customized HIT.